# How can I get a process entry point address

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I create a suspended process `test.exe` like this:

```
CreateProcess(
    TEXT( "C:\\Documents and Settings\\willy\\桌面\\project\\test.exe" ), 
    TEXT( "test.exe" ),
    NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi
);
```

How can I get the entry point/startup/main address for the process `test.exe` after it has been created?

Should I look up PE file information or use API like `ReadProcessMemory()` or `VirtualQueryEx()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a process with `CREATE_SUSPENDED`, it starts out in ntdll initialization code. This is of little use for finding the .exe's entry point; you must examine the exe file's headers directly for this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinNT.h>

DWORD FindEntryPointAddress(_TCHAR *exeFile)
{
    BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION bhfi;
    HANDLE hMapping;
    char *lpBase;
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(exeFile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        fail("Opening exe file", GetLastError());

    if (!GetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, &bhfi))
        fail("GetFileInformationByHandle", GetLastError());

    hMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, bhfi.nFileSizeHigh, bhfi.nFileSizeLow, NULL);
    if (!hMapping)
        fail("CreateFileMapping", GetLastError());
    lpBase = (char *)MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, bhfi.nFileSizeLow);
    if (!lpBase)
        fail("MapViewOfFile", GetLastError());

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpBase;
    if (dosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
        fail("bad dos header signature", 0);

    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)(lpBase + dosHeader->e_lfanew);
    if (ntHeader->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        fail("bad nt header signature", 0);

    DWORD pEntryPoint = ntHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + ntHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;

    UnmapViewOfFile((LPCVOID)lpBase);
    CloseHandle(hMapping);
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return pEntryPoint;
}
```

Note that this address is of the first code that executes after DLL initialization completes. It may not be (and usually isn't) equal to the address of `main` or `WinMain`; it's usually some C library startup code statically linked into the EXE.

Also note that this will fail if the EXE is relocatable and ASLR is enabled, as the EXE may be loaded at a different base address. You'll have to find where the EXE base address is and use that instead of `ntHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase` in this case.

Comment: But a PE image can get relocated by the loader and the actual entry point address will be different from the one specified in the `AddressOfEntryPoint` field of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`.

Comment: @Alex, are relocatable EXE images allowed on windows?

Comment: EnumProcessModules() returns image base in its HMODULE output, but if the process is created as suspended, it seems like the module list isn't initialized yet after CreateProcess() and EnumProcessModules() fails with ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY. Not sure how to catch the moment before the 1st instruction of the image gets executed. Perhaps the debugging functionality will help.

Comment: @Alex, it might be possible to use QueryWorkingSet and GetMappedFileName instead; you'd basically go searching for some file mappings that correspond to your EXE. Haven't tested this technique though.

Comment: Alternately find the part in ntdll that invokes the exe entry point , set a bp and single step to find the entry point

Answer (score 8):

OK, I've hacked up a 32-bit only solution that gets the image base address from the process' PEB.

File **EntryPt.c**:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

// To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS
// and compile with -DPSAPI_VERSION=1

NTSTATUS (NTAPI *pNtQueryInformationProcess)(HANDLE, /*enum _PROCESSINFOCLASS*/DWORD, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG) = NULL;

extern PVOID GetPeb(HANDLE ProcessHandle);

// PEB definition comes from winternl.h. This is a 32-bit PEB.
typedef struct _PEB
{
  BYTE                          Reserved1[2];
  BYTE                          BeingDebugged;
  BYTE                          Reserved2[1];
  PVOID                         Reserved3[2]; // Reserved3[1] points to PEB
/*
  PPEB_LDR_DATA                 Ldr;
  PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS  ProcessParameters;
  BYTE                          Reserved4[104];
  PVOID                         Reserved5[52];
  PPS_POST_PROCESS_INIT_ROUTINE PostProcessInitRoutine;
  BYTE                          Reserved6[128];
  PVOID                         Reserved7[1];
  ULONG                         SessionId;
*/
} PEB, *PPEB;

int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;

    PPEB pPeb;
    PVOID pImage, pEntry;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNtHeaders;
    LONG e_lfanew;
    SIZE_T NumberOfBytesRead;

    pNtQueryInformationProcess = (NTSTATUS(NTAPI*)(HANDLE, /*enum _PROCESSINFOCLASS*/DWORD, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG))
        GetProcAddress(
            GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")), 
            TEXT("NtQueryInformationProcess"));

    if (pNtQueryInformationProcess == NULL)
    {
        printf("GetProcAddress(ntdll.dll, NtQueryInformationProcess) failed with error 0x%08X\n",
               GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&StartupInfo, 0, sizeof(StartupInfo));
    memset(&ProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(ProcessInfo));

    if (!CreateProcess(
      NULL,
      (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : argv[0],
      NULL,
      NULL,
      FALSE,
      CREATE_SUSPENDED,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      &StartupInfo,
      &ProcessInfo))
    {
        printf("CreateProcess() failed with error 0x%08X\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Current process:\n");
    pPeb = GetPeb(GetCurrentProcess());
    printf("PEB: 0x%08X\n", pPeb);
    pImage = pPeb->Reserved3[1];
    printf("Image base: 0x%08X\n", pImage);
    pNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((PCHAR)pImage + ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)pImage)->e_lfanew);
    pEntry = (PVOID)((PCHAR)pImage + pNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint);
    printf("Image entry point: 0x%08X\n", pEntry);

    printf("\n");

    printf("Child process:\n");
    pPeb = GetPeb(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    printf("PEB: 0x%08X\n", pPeb);

    if (!ReadProcessMemory(
      ProcessInfo.hProcess,
      &pPeb->Reserved3[1],
      &pImage,
      sizeof(pImage),
      &NumberOfBytesRead) || NumberOfBytesRead != sizeof(pImage))
    {
        printf("ReadProcessMemory(&pImage) failed with error 0x%08X\n", GetLastError());
        goto End;
    }
    printf("Image base: 0x%08X\n", pImage);

    if (!ReadProcessMemory(
      ProcessInfo.hProcess,
      (PCHAR)pImage + offsetof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, e_lfanew),
      &e_lfanew,
      sizeof(e_lfanew),
      &NumberOfBytesRead) || NumberOfBytesRead != sizeof(e_lfanew))
    {
        printf("ReadProcessMemory(&e_lfanew) failed with error 0x%08X\n", GetLastError());
        goto End;
    }
    pNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((PCHAR)pImage + e_lfanew);

    if (!ReadProcessMemory(
      ProcessInfo.hProcess,
      (PCHAR)pNtHeaders + offsetof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint),
      &pEntry,
      sizeof(pEntry),
      &NumberOfBytesRead) || NumberOfBytesRead != sizeof(pEntry))
    {
        printf("ReadProcessMemory(&pEntry) failed with error 0x%08X\n", GetLastError());
        goto End;
    }
    pEntry = (PVOID)((PCHAR)pImage + (SIZE_T)pEntry);
    printf("Image entry point: 0x%08X\n", pEntry);

End:

    TerminateProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 0);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

File **GetPeb.c**:

```
#include <ntddk.h>

extern NTSTATUS (NTAPI *pNtQueryInformationProcess)(
  HANDLE ProcessHandle,
  PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
  PVOID ProcessInformation,
  ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
  PULONG ReturnLength);

PVOID GetPeb(HANDLE ProcessHandle)
{
  NTSTATUS status;
  PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
  PVOID pPeb;

  memset(&pbi, 0, sizeof(pbi));

  status = pNtQueryInformationProcess(
    ProcessHandle,
    ProcessBasicInformation,
    &pbi,
    sizeof(pbi),
    NULL);

  pPeb = NULL;

  if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
  {
    pPeb = pbi.PebBaseAddress;
  }

  return pPeb;
}
```

Compiled with Open Watcom 1.9 via this batch file:

```
set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%WATCOM%\H\NT;%WATCOM%\H\NT\DDK;
wcl386 /we /wx /q /d2 -DPSAPI_VERSION=1 EntryPt.c GetPeb.c %WATCOM%\lib386\nt\psapi.lib
```

Output (run on Windows XP):

```
>EntryPt.exe

Current process:
PEB: 0x7FFDD000
Image base: 0x00400000
Image entry point: 0x004013E8

Child process:
PEB: 0x7FFDC000
Image base: 0x00400000
Image entry point: 0x004013E8

>EntryPt.exe calc.exe
Current process:
PEB: 0x7FFDC000
Image base: 0x00400000
Image entry point: 0x004013E8

Child process:
PEB: 0x7FFDB000
Image base: 0x01000000
Image entry point: 0x01012475
```

This code uses [NtQueryInformationProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that may change in future versions of the OS. It also uses [undocumented definition](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Process/PEB.html) of the [PEB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). This code won't work on 64-bit Windows unless modified appropriately (possibly taking into account [WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and it may not work with future versions of Windows.

Comment: Why do you have to read memory from the child process, when getting the image base address please? You did not read memory when getting the image base from the parent process.

Comment: @Goaler444 I did read the memory in the parent process, here: `pPeb = GetPeb(GetCurrentProcess()); printf("PEB: 0x%08X\n", pPeb); pImage = pPeb->Reserved3[1]; printf("Image base: 0x%08X\n", pImage);`. The actual read occurs in `pImage = pPeb->Reserved3[1];`.

Comment: @XiaoJia Relocated by Windows? Sure, why not?

Comment: @Alexey When relocated, pImage changes (!= 400000) and AddressOfEntryPoint is a fixed offset, so it will work, correct?

Comment: @XiaoJia If you relocate the executable, how can you not relocate its entry point??? Further, the PE format has the entry point relative to the image base. So, you move the whole thing to a new base address, and add the same relative entry point.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze In that case, why do we need to peek into the undocumented PEB?  If CreateProcess with DEBUG_PROCESS, we will receive CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO which contains lpBaseOfImage (base address of the executable image that the process is running) and hFile (we can read entry point from here).

Comment: @XiaoJia You should be able to do it like that too, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10655759/968261).