# Is it possible to call a non-exported function that resides in an exe?

Tags: c, windows, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I'd like to call a function that resides in a 3rd-party .exe and obtain its result.  It seems like there *should* be a way, as long as I know the function address, calling-convention, etc... but I don't know how.

**Does anyone know how I would do this?**

I realize that any solution would be a non-standard hack, but there *must* be a way!

---

My non-nefarious use-case:  I'm reverse engineering a file-format for my software.  The calculations in this function are too complex for my tiny brain to figure out; I've been able to pull the assembly-code directly into my own DLL for testing, but of course I can't release that, as that would be stealing.  I will be assuming users already have this particular application pre-installed so my software will run.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a non-exported function in a DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918234/calling-a-non-exported-function-in-a-dll)

Comment: well if you know the offset to the function in the exe you could load the exe into memory and then jump, appropriately, to the correct place in the EXE.

Comment: @Mooing: I'm not so sure that's a duplicate; getting a handle to an .exe is not as simple as calling `GetModuleHandle()`, since it will not already be loaded in the same process like a .dll.  Using `LoadLibrary()` instead *might* work, though; I will have to try it out.

Comment: @Goz: I do know the offset *(or I can find it using signature scanning)*.  But I'm not exactly sure how to *"load the exe into memory and then jump to the correct place."*  If you provided working code that does just that, I'd accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: I failed to notice that one was exe and one was dll.  I'm pretty sure `LoadLibrary` does not work on exes though.

Comment: @Mooing: According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it does.  I've honestly never tried, though.

Comment: From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "LoadLibrary can also be used to load other executable modules. For example, the function can specify an .exe file to get a handle that can be used in FindResource or LoadResource."  But beware of position-dependent code.

Comment: You're going to run into trouble whenever that other program gets patched or updated. Or if the other vendor finds out and intentionally tweaks their program to stop yours from working. What you describe is theoretically possible, but it isn't sound engineering practice.

Comment: @BlueRaja: literally read the exe into memory using something like fopen.  The function stars at memory allocation start + offset ... you'll need to perform an assembler jump, however, to switch execution to that point.  On a number of platforms (such as x86) you'll also need to mark the code as executable.

Comment: @Goz: That assumes that the code is [position-independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code), which it very likely is not.

Comment: @Raymond: Patch problems can be mitigated using the methods to determine function addresses that other software (like SourceMod) uses - signature scanning.  However, I realize it is a rickety and unsound practice, but if I can't reverse engineer the code myself, I can't think of another option.  Anyways, if it *can* be done, it *should* be documented at least somewhere on the internet, but as far as I can tell it's not, so this is still a worthwhile question.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield:  Fair point ... so you'd need to patch the various jumps ... joy

Comment: Generally speaking, unsound engineering practices tend not to be well-documented precisely because they are unsound.

Comment: @Raymond: Then do you have a better solution?  Saying *"this is bad practice"* is pointless if there is no **good** practice that will solve the problem.

Comment: @BlueRaja: In this case, the "good practice" would be to ask the developer of the software you're trying to use to either provide a library that can parse the file format you're interested in or some documentation on the file format.  Maybe offer them some $$$ to license it if they won't give it away for free.  Of course, if the developer is no longer in business, then you may not have any better options.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644717/find-a-function-by-it-signature-in-windows-dll

Comment: @Adam: That is not possible in the vast majority of cases, including mine *(I am writing a free utility in my spare time, this isn't for a business)*.

Comment: If the discussion here continues heading down the road of whether this is legal or not then I'm going to close this question - if OP needs advice about that then he can pay for qualified legal advice seeing as we're not lawyers. Please stick to the jist of the question about whether it is technically feasible to do this. Also, please move this discussion to a chat room, it's being flagged by our systems and the next mod that comes along may not be quite as forgiving :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I've put together a prototype.

This program creates another instance of itself as a debugged child process.

An automatic breakpoint will be encountered before main() and CRT initialization code. This is when we can change the memory and registers of the debugged process to make it execute a function of interest. And that's what the program does.

It tries to catch and handle all the bad situations (e.g. unexpected exceptions) and reports them as errors.

One bad situation is actually a good one. It's the #UD exception from the UD2 instruction that the program places into the debugged process. It uses this #UD to stop the process execution after the function of interest has returned.

A few more notes:

1. This code is 32-bit only. I didn't even try to make it 64-bit compilable or support 64-bit child processes.
2. This code will likely leak handles. See the Windows Debug API function descriptions on MSDN to find out where they need to be closed.
3. This code is a proof of concept only and does not support passing and returning data via pointers or registers other than EAX, ECX and EDX. You'll have to extend it as necessary.
4. <strike>This code requires some privileges in order to be able to create and fully debug a process. You may have to worry about this if your program's users aren't admins.</strike>

Enjoy.

Code:

```
// file: unexported.c
//
// compile with Open Watcom C/C++: wcl386 /q /wx /we /s unexported.c
//   (Note: "/s" is needed to avoid stack check calls from the "unexported"
//    functions, these calls are through a pointer, and it'll be
//    uninitialized in our case.)
//
// compile with MinGW gcc 4.6.2: gcc unexported.c -o unexported.exe
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <limits.h>

#ifndef C_ASSERT
#define C_ASSERT(expr) extern char CAssertExtern[(expr)?1:-1]
#endif

// Compile as a 32-bit app only.
C_ASSERT(sizeof(void*) * CHAR_BIT == 32);

#define EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(X) { X, #X }

const struct
{
  DWORD Code;
  PCSTR Name;
} ExcCodesAndNames[] =
{
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_ARRAY_BOUNDS_EXCEEDED),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_FLT_DENORMAL_OPERAND),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_FLT_INEXACT_RESULT),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_FLT_INVALID_OPERATION),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_FLT_OVERFLOW),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_FLT_STACK_CHECK),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_FLT_UNDERFLOW),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_INVALID_DISPOSITION),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE_EXCEPTION),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(EXCEPTION_GUARD_PAGE),
  EXC_CODE_AND_NAME(DBG_CONTROL_C),
  { 0xE06D7363, "C++ EH exception" }
};

PCSTR GetExceptionName(DWORD code)
{
  DWORD i;

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(ExcCodesAndNames) / sizeof(ExcCodesAndNames[0]); i++)
  {
    if (ExcCodesAndNames[i].Code == code)
    {
      return ExcCodesAndNames[i].Name;
    }
  }

  return "?";
}

typedef enum tCallConv
{
  CallConvCdecl,    // Params on stack; caller removes params
  CallConvStdCall,  // Params on stack; callee removes params
  CallConvFastCall  // Params in ECX, EDX and on stack; callee removes params
} tCallConv;

DWORD Execute32bitFunctionFromExe(PCSTR ExeName,
                                  int FunctionAddressIsRelative,
                                  DWORD FunctionAddress,
                                  tCallConv CallConvention,
                                  DWORD CodeDataStackSize,
                                  ULONG64* ResultEdxEax,
                                  DWORD DwordParamsCount,
                                  .../* DWORD params */)
{
  STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
  PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
  DWORD dwContinueStatus = DBG_CONTINUE; // exception continuation
  DEBUG_EVENT dbgEvt;
  UCHAR* procMem = NULL;
  DWORD breakPointCount = 0;
  DWORD err = ERROR_SUCCESS;
  DWORD ecxEdxParams[2] = { 0, 0 };
  DWORD imageBase = 0;
  CONTEXT ctx;
  va_list ap;

  va_start(ap, DwordParamsCount);

  *ResultEdxEax = 0;

  memset(&startupInfo, 0, sizeof(startupInfo));
  startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
  memset(&processInfo, 0, sizeof(processInfo));

  if (!CreateProcess(
    NULL,
    (LPSTR)ExeName,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS, // DEBUG_PROCESS,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &startupInfo,
    &processInfo))
  {
    printf("CreateProcess() failed with error 0x%08X\n",
           err = GetLastError());
    goto Cleanup;
  }

  printf("Process 0x%08X (0x%08X) \"%s\" created,\n"
         "  Thread 0x%08X (0x%08X) created\n",
         processInfo.dwProcessId,
         processInfo.hProcess,
         ExeName,
         processInfo.dwThreadId,
         processInfo.hThread);

  procMem = VirtualAllocEx(
    processInfo.hProcess,
    NULL,
    CodeDataStackSize,
    MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
    PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

  if (procMem == NULL)
  {
    printf("VirtualAllocEx() failed with error 0x%08X\n",
           err = GetLastError());
    goto Cleanup;
  }

  printf("Allocated RWX memory in process 0x%08X (0x%08X) "
         "at address 0x%08X\n",
         processInfo.dwProcessId,
         processInfo.hProcess,
         procMem);

  while (dwContinueStatus)
  {
    // Wait for a debugging event to occur. The second parameter indicates
    // that the function does not return until a debugging event occurs.
    if (!WaitForDebugEvent(&dbgEvt, INFINITE))
    {
      printf("WaitForDebugEvent() failed with error 0x%08X\n",
             err = GetLastError());
      goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Process the debugging event code.
    switch (dbgEvt.dwDebugEventCode)
    {
    case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:
    // Process the exception code. When handling
    // exceptions, remember to set the continuation
    // status parameter (dwContinueStatus). This value
    // is used by the ContinueDebugEvent function.

      printf("%s (%s) Exception in process 0x%08X, thread 0x%08X\n"
             "  Exc. Code = 0x%08X (%s), Instr. Address = 0x%08X",
             dbgEvt.u.Exception.dwFirstChance ?
               "First Chance" : "Last Chance",
             dbgEvt.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionFlags ?
               "non-continuable" : "continuable",
             dbgEvt.dwProcessId,
             dbgEvt.dwThreadId,
             dbgEvt.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode,
             GetExceptionName(dbgEvt.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode),
             dbgEvt.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress);

      if (dbgEvt.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode ==
          EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
      {
        ULONG_PTR* info = dbgEvt.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation;
        printf(",\n  Access Address = 0x%08X, Access = 0x%08X (%s)",
               (DWORD)info[1],
               (DWORD)info[0],
               (info[0] == 0) ?
                 "read" : ((info[0] == 1) ? "write" : "execute")); // 8 = DEP
      }

      printf("\n");

      // Get the thread context (register state).
      // We'll need to either display it (in case of unexpected exceptions) or
      // modify it (to execute our code) or read it (to get the results of
      // execution).
      memset(&ctx, 0, sizeof(ctx));
      ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_INTEGER | CONTEXT_CONTROL;
      if (!GetThreadContext(processInfo.hThread, &ctx))
      {
        printf("GetThreadContext() failed with error 0x%08X\n",
               err = GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
      }

#if 0
      printf("  EAX=0x%08X EBX=0x%08X ECX=0x%08X EDX=0x%08X EFLAGS=0x%08X\n"
             "  ESI=0x%08X EDI=0x%08X EBP=0x%08X ESP=0x%08X EIP=0x%08X\n",
             ctx.Eax, ctx.Ebx, ctx.Ecx, ctx.Edx, ctx.EFlags, 
             ctx.Esi, ctx.Edi, ctx.Ebp, ctx.Esp, ctx.Eip);
#endif

      if (dbgEvt.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT &&
          breakPointCount == 0)
      {
        // Update the context so our code can be executed
        DWORD mem, i, data;
        SIZE_T numberOfBytesCopied;

        mem = (DWORD)procMem + CodeDataStackSize;

        // Child process memory layout (inside the procMem[] buffer):
        //
        //    higher
        //  addresses
        //      .
        //      .     UD2 instruction (causes #UD, indicator of successful
        //      .     completion of FunctionAddress())
        //      .
        //      .     last on-stack parameter for FunctionAddress()
        //      .     ...
        //      .     first on-stack parameter for FunctionAddress()
        //      .
        //      .     address of UD2 instruction (as if "call FunctionAddress"
        //      .     executed just before it and is going to return to UD2)
        //      .     (ESP will point here)
        //      .
        //      .     FunctionAddress()'s stack
        //      .
        //    lower
        //  addresses

        mem -= 2;
        data = 0x0B0F; // 0x0F, 0x0B = UD2 instruction
        if (!WriteProcessMemory(processInfo.hProcess,
                                (PVOID)mem,
                                &data,
                                2,
                                &numberOfBytesCopied))
        {
ErrWriteMem1:
          printf("WriteProcessMemory() failed with error 0x%08X\n",
                 err = GetLastError());
          goto Cleanup;
        }
        else if (numberOfBytesCopied != 2)
        {
ErrWriteMem2:
          printf("WriteProcessMemory() failed with error 0x%08X\n",
                 err = ERROR_BAD_LENGTH);
          goto Cleanup;
        }

        // Copy function parameters.

        mem &= 0xFFFFFFFC; // align the address for the stack

        for (i = 0; i < DwordParamsCount; i++)
        {
          if (CallConvention == CallConvFastCall && i < 2)
          {
            ecxEdxParams[i] = va_arg(ap, DWORD);
          }
          else
          {
            data = va_arg(ap, DWORD);
            if (!WriteProcessMemory(processInfo.hProcess,
                                    (DWORD*)mem - DwordParamsCount + i,
                                    &data,
                                    sizeof(data),
                                    &numberOfBytesCopied))
            {
              goto ErrWriteMem1;
            }
            else if (numberOfBytesCopied != sizeof(data))
            {
              goto ErrWriteMem2;
            }
          }
        }

        // Adjust what will become ESP according to the number of on-stack parameters.
        for (i = 0; i < DwordParamsCount; i++)
        {
          if (CallConvention != CallConvFastCall || i >= 2)
          {
            mem -= 4;
          }
        }

        // Store the function return address.
        mem -= 4;
        data = (DWORD)procMem + CodeDataStackSize - 2; // address of UD2
        if (!WriteProcessMemory(processInfo.hProcess,
                                (PVOID)mem,
                                &data,
                                sizeof(data),
                                &numberOfBytesCopied))
        {
          goto ErrWriteMem1;
        }
        else if (numberOfBytesCopied != sizeof(data))
        {
          goto ErrWriteMem2;
        }

        // Last-minute preparations for execution...
        // Set up the registers (ECX, EDX, EFLAGS, EIP, ESP).

        if (CallConvention == CallConvFastCall)
        {
          if (DwordParamsCount >= 1) ctx.Ecx = ecxEdxParams[0];
          if (DwordParamsCount >= 2) ctx.Edx = ecxEdxParams[1];
        }

        ctx.EFlags &= ~(1 << 10); // clear DF for string instructions
        ctx.Eip = FunctionAddress + imageBase * !!FunctionAddressIsRelative;
        ctx.Esp = mem;

        if (!SetThreadContext(processInfo.hThread, &ctx))
        {
          printf("SetThreadContext() failed with error 0x%08X\n",
                 err = GetLastError());
          goto Cleanup;
        }

        printf("Copied code/data to the process\n");

#if 0
        for (i = esp; i < (DWORD)procMem + CodeDataStackSize; i++)
        {
          data = 0;
          ReadProcessMemory(processInfo.hProcess,
                            (void*)i,
                            &data,
                            1,
                            &numberOfBytesCopied);
          printf("E[SI]P = 0x%08X: 0x%02X\n", i, data);
        }
#endif

        breakPointCount++;
        dwContinueStatus = DBG_CONTINUE; // continue execution of our code
      }
      else if (dbgEvt.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION &&
               breakPointCount == 1 &&
               ctx.Eip == (DWORD)procMem + CodeDataStackSize - 2/*UD2 size*/)
      {
        // The code has finished execution as expected.
        // Collect the results.

        *ResultEdxEax = ((ULONG64)ctx.Edx << 32) | ctx.Eax;

        printf("Copied code/data from the process\n");

        dwContinueStatus = 0; // stop debugging
      }
      else
      {
        // Unexpected event. Do not continue execution.

        printf("  EAX=0x%08X EBX=0x%08X ECX=0x%08X EDX=0x%08X EFLAGS=0x%08X\n"
               "  ESI=0x%08X EDI=0x%08X EBP=0x%08X ESP=0x%08X EIP=0x%08X\n",
               ctx.Eax, ctx.Ebx, ctx.Ecx, ctx.Edx, ctx.EFlags, 
               ctx.Esi, ctx.Edi, ctx.Ebp, ctx.Esp, ctx.Eip);

        err = dbgEvt.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode;
        goto Cleanup;
      }
      break; // case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:

    case CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
    // As needed, examine or change the registers of the
    // process's initial thread with the GetThreadContext and
    // SetThreadContext functions; read from and write to the
    // process's virtual memory with the ReadProcessMemory and
    // WriteProcessMemory functions; and suspend and resume
    // thread execution with the SuspendThread and ResumeThread
    // functions. Be sure to close the handle to the process image
    // file with CloseHandle.
      printf("Process 0x%08X (0x%08X) "
             "created, base = 0x%08X,\n"
             "  Thread 0x%08X (0x%08X) created, start = 0x%08X\n",
             dbgEvt.dwProcessId,
             dbgEvt.u.CreateProcessInfo.hProcess,
             dbgEvt.u.CreateProcessInfo.lpBaseOfImage,
             dbgEvt.dwThreadId,
             dbgEvt.u.CreateProcessInfo.hThread,
             dbgEvt.u.CreateProcessInfo.lpStartAddress);
      // Found image base!
      imageBase = (DWORD)dbgEvt.u.CreateProcessInfo.lpBaseOfImage;
      dwContinueStatus = DBG_CONTINUE;
      break;

    case EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
    // Display the process's exit code.
      printf("Process 0x%08X exited, exit code = 0x%08X\n",
             dbgEvt.dwProcessId,
             dbgEvt.u.ExitProcess.dwExitCode);
      // Unexpected event. Do not continue execution.
      err = ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND;
      goto Cleanup;

    case CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT:
    case EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT:
    case LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
    case UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
    case OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_EVENT:
      dwContinueStatus = DBG_CONTINUE;
      break;

    case RIP_EVENT:
      printf("RIP: Error = 0x%08X, Type = 0x%08X\n",
             dbgEvt.u.RipInfo.dwError,
             dbgEvt.u.RipInfo.dwType);
      // Unexpected event. Do not continue execution.
      err = dbgEvt.u.RipInfo.dwError;
      goto Cleanup;
    } // end of switch (dbgEvt.dwDebugEventCode)

    // Resume executing the thread that reported the debugging event.
    if (dwContinueStatus)
    {
      if (!ContinueDebugEvent(dbgEvt.dwProcessId,
                              dbgEvt.dwThreadId,
                              dwContinueStatus))
      {
        printf("ContinueDebugEvent() failed with error 0x%08X\n",
               err = GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
      }
    }
  } // end of while (dwContinueStatus)

  err = ERROR_SUCCESS;

Cleanup:

  if (processInfo.hProcess != NULL)
  {
    if (procMem != NULL)
    {
      VirtualFreeEx(processInfo.hProcess, procMem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    }
    TerminateProcess(processInfo.hProcess, 0);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
  }

  va_end(ap);

  return err;
}

int __cdecl FunctionCdecl(int x, int y, int z)
{
  return x + y + z;
}

int __stdcall FunctionStdCall(int x, int y, int z)
{
  return x * y * z;
}

ULONG64 __fastcall FunctionFastCall(DWORD x, DWORD y, DWORD z)
{
  return (ULONG64)x * y + z;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  DWORD err;
  ULONG64 resultEdxEax;

  err = Execute32bitFunctionFromExe(argv[0]/*ExeName*/,
                                    1/*FunctionAddressIsRelative*/,
                                    (DWORD)&FunctionCdecl -
                                      (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                    CallConvCdecl,
                                    4096/*CodeDataStackSize*/,
                                    &resultEdxEax,
                                    3/*DwordParamsCount*/,
                                    2, 3, 4);
  if (err == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    printf("2 + 3 + 4 = %d\n", (int)resultEdxEax);

  err = Execute32bitFunctionFromExe(argv[0]/*ExeName*/,
                                    1/*FunctionAddressIsRelative*/,
                                    (DWORD)&FunctionStdCall -
                                      (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                    CallConvStdCall,
                                    4096/*CodeDataStackSize*/,
                                    &resultEdxEax,
                                    3/*DwordParamsCount*/,
                                    -2, 3, 4);
  if (err == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    printf("-2 * 3 * 4 = %d\n", (int)resultEdxEax);

  err = Execute32bitFunctionFromExe(argv[0]/*ExeName*/,
                                    1/*FunctionAddressIsRelative*/,
                                    (DWORD)&FunctionFastCall -
                                      (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                    CallConvFastCall,
                                    4096/*CodeDataStackSize*/,
                                    &resultEdxEax,
                                    3/*DwordParamsCount*/,
                                    -1, -1, -1);
  if (err == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    printf("0xFFFFFFFF * 0xFFFFFFFF + 0xFFFFFFFF = 0x%llX\n",
           (unsigned long long)resultEdxEax);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Process 0x00001514 (0x00000040) "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\Alex\unexported.exe" cre
ated,
  Thread 0x00000CB0 (0x0000003C) created
Allocated RWX memory in process 0x00001514 (0x00000040) at address 0x002B0000
Process 0x00001514 (0x00000044) created, base = 0x00400000,
  Thread 0x00000CB0 (0x00000048) created, start = 0x0040126C
First Chance (continuable) Exception in process 0x00001514, thread 0x00000CB0
  Exc. Code = 0x80000003 (EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT), Instr. Address = 0x77090FAB
Copied code/data to the process
First Chance (continuable) Exception in process 0x00001514, thread 0x00000CB0
  Exc. Code = 0xC000001D (EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION), Instr. Address = 0x002
B0FFE
Copied code/data from the process
2 + 3 + 4 = 9
Process 0x00001828 (0x0000003C) "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\Alex\unexported.exe" cre
ated,
  Thread 0x00001690 (0x00000040) created
Allocated RWX memory in process 0x00001828 (0x0000003C) at address 0x002B0000
Process 0x00001828 (0x0000006C) created, base = 0x00400000,
  Thread 0x00001690 (0x00000074) created, start = 0x0040126C
First Chance (continuable) Exception in process 0x00001828, thread 0x00001690
  Exc. Code = 0x80000003 (EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT), Instr. Address = 0x77090FAB
Copied code/data to the process
First Chance (continuable) Exception in process 0x00001828, thread 0x00001690
  Exc. Code = 0xC000001D (EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION), Instr. Address = 0x002
B0FFE
Copied code/data from the process
-2 * 3 * 4 = -24
Process 0x00001388 (0x00000040) "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\Alex\unexported.exe" cre
ated,
  Thread 0x00001098 (0x0000003C) created
Allocated RWX memory in process 0x00001388 (0x00000040) at address 0x002B0000
Process 0x00001388 (0x0000008C) created, base = 0x00400000,
  Thread 0x00001098 (0x00000090) created, start = 0x0040126C
First Chance (continuable) Exception in process 0x00001388, thread 0x00001098
  Exc. Code = 0x80000003 (EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT), Instr. Address = 0x77090FAB
Copied code/data to the process
First Chance (continuable) Exception in process 0x00001388, thread 0x00001098
  Exc. Code = 0xC000001D (EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION), Instr. Address = 0x002
B0FFE
Copied code/data from the process
0xFFFFFFFF * 0xFFFFFFFF + 0xFFFFFFFF = 0xFFFFFFFF00000000
```

Comment: I don't see anything in there that requires admin privilege.  Did you have something specific in mind or did you just mean you haven't tested it from a non-admin account?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I didn't test it from a non-admin account and, yes, there's something specific that I meant too. MSDN says that in various places of the above code specific access rights must be available: PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, PROCESS_VM_READ, PROCESS_VM_WRITE, THREAD_GET_CONTEXT, THREAD_SET_CONTEXT, THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION. I do not yet know everything about them. OTOH, it seems like "SeDebugPrivilege" isn't needed in this case.

Comment: AFAIK, even standard user accounts have unrestricted access rights to their own processes and threads, so I don't think any of those will be problems.  SeDebugPrivilege is only required to debug other user's processes.  OTOH, there's a risk of anti-virus software flagging or blocking this sort of thing, but that will happen whether you're an admin or not.  If I get a chance I'll try this out as a standard user when I get back to work on Monday.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I just created a standard user and ran the above code under it and it worked.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible but not trivial. And yes, this is a very dirty hack.

In some cases loading the EXE file with LoadLibrary is enough. The returned HMODULE is actually the base address of the loaded EXE. Cast it to a suitable int type, add your relative function address to that, cast it back to a function pointer and call the function through that pointer.

Unfortunately, the EXE file may have its relocation info stripped. It means that the EXE will be expecting to run from a specific address. In this case, you have to change your own program's base address to avoid conflict. Check out your linker's docs, there should be an option to do that. After that, LoadLibrary will load the EXE in its preferred base address and hopefully all should work fine.

There is some very useful info on this [here](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Using_an_exe_as_a_dll.html). Make sure to check the update at the end of the page for a different technique that may work better in some cases.

**Edit:** As Alex correctly stated in the comment below, if the function relies on some initialized value, or it calls such a function, including most C runtime functions, it will be much harder to make it work. One can identify the initialization functions and call them beforehand but using [debug API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809754.aspx) may be your best bet in those situations.

Comment: The function, however, should not rely on variables pre-initialized at run time (e.g. CRT styff). If it does, it's going to be harder to make it work. Also, I think, by using some debugging APIs one can fully control execution of a process, e.g. alter its memory and registers and execute instructions. This may let you avoid code/data relocation.

Comment: It *does* rely on an initialized value, but the value is initialized directly in the .data section (that is, it's embedded in the .exe).  Will that be an issue?  No Windows or C-library calls are made.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, you can set the value yourself anyway. Also, if you know exactly where the function is in the EXE, you can load the EXE yourself, and rewrite the call addresses to match your own program's base. So what you are trying to do is very much possible, just inconvenient.

Comment: @Amigable: That's good to hear :)  But I still don't know *how* I would do all that - do you have any example code?

Comment: No, sorry, don't know how to do it myself. It would be something like a disassembler I imagine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of loading the EXE into your process, two better (IMO) ways:

1) Use debugging API (or something like PyDbg) to start the target under a debugger, then set up the arguments in the stack, set EIP to the necessary address, put breakpoint on the return address, and resume.

2) make a small DLL with some IPC to communicate with your program, inject it into target (there are several ways to do it, the easiest is probably keyboard hooking) and have it call the necessary code. Or you could use an existing too that can do it, e.g. [Intel's PIN](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/publicity/pin/docs/39599/Pin/html/group__PIN__CONTROL.html#g8fa128a4393b96cc7f292d17d2ef0ba4).