# Inter-process Hooking

Tags: c++, hook, ipc

Is it possible to use hooks to jump to another process' running memory, and then jump back, without anything like a DLL injection?

For instance, if process `A` has a procedure `foo` and process `B` has a procedure `bar` with an identical prototype to `foo` (used for a hook), is it possible to hook `foo` to jmp to `bar`, assuming both processes are running?

EDIT: This needs to be done on Windows.

Comment: You may be interested in [this question and my answer to it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10487165/968261).

Comment: Btw, we're talking about Windows, right?

Comment: @Alex - Yes, Windows. I'll add that in there. I'm visiting the link now.

Comment: @Alex - Alright, read it. Makes sense. However, the EXE will be loaded in its own process; that is the issue.

Comment: That's exactly the scenario in my program, there are two processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process by definition is a sandbox. If you even by mistake step outside your address space it's raised and caught as a SIG_USR signal and reported as a segmentation fault

Having said that there are inter process communication mechanisms such as shared memory -shmem, Pipes and sockets that you can use to communicate across processes.

Edit : 
There are RPC ( remote procedure calls) mechanisms available as well Such as CORBA That provide remote method invocation.

Comment: Can shared memory be executed?

Comment: @Dani : I am not sure how would you mark a shared memory as executable. Generally your executable's  `.txt` gets loaded into the memory and only that can be executed. What can be done is, we can get some sheared memory from the os and write some instructions there and from your code make a jump to that address to execute it. but still it would be visible only to your process and any processes that are also accessing this shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

Each process in Windows (as well as in Unix and probably vast majority of other modern OS) has it's own virtual memory space, which usually maps to different physical addresses. Consequently injecting a DLL into the address space of another process is the only method to hook anything in that process. On the other hand once you have a DLL in that process, there are plenty of things you can do there, eg. spawn your own thread and communicate with the parent process using Windows messages (as one of the easiest communication methods in Windows).