# Handle AppCrash of created process

Tags: c++, windows, exception, process

In my project I have to run an external application to do some work for me.

Unfortuneatly this application is not very stable and it crashes when given input is not what this application is expecting.

I'm doing my best to ensure that all input is valid, but I also want to handle situations that were not prediceted and instead of Windows AppCrash message display my own message.

So my question is: **Is there a way to handle the process AppCrash event?**

Here is the code that I'm using to launch the app:

```
bool runExternalCalibrationConsole(const std::wstring &wsCalibFolderPath)
{
    wchar_t AppName[512];
    wchar_t CmdLine[2 * MAX_PATH];

    std::wstring app = L"D:\\ExternalCalibrationConsole.exe";
    std::wstring cmd = L"D:\\ExternalCalibrationConsole.exe";
    cmd += L" ";
    cmd += wsCalibFolderPath;
    swprintf_s(AppName, 512, app.c_str());
    swprintf_s(CmdLine, 512, cmd.c_str());
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
    memset(&processInformation, 0, sizeof(processInformation));
    memset(&startupInfo, 0, sizeof(startupInfo));
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);

    BOOL result;
    char tempCmdLine[MAX_PATH * 2];  //Needed since CreateProcessW may change the contents of CmdLine
    if (CmdLine != NULL)
    {
        //_tcscpy_s(tempCmdLine, MAX_PATH * 2, CmdLine);
        result = ::CreateProcess(AppName, CmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
        if (result){
            printf("Process created\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error creating process\n");
            return -10;
        }
        WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
        DWORD exitCode;
        result = GetExitCodeProcess(processInformation.hProcess, &exitCode);

        CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess);

        return exitCode;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create the child process as debuggable (e.g. pass `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` to `CreateProcess()`) and then handle debug events from it with the help of `WaitForDebugEvent()` and `ContinueDebugEvent()`.

See [MSDN: WaitForDebugEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681423(v=vs.85).aspx), [MSDN: Writing the Debugger's Main Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681675(v=vs.85).aspx), [An example of setting that up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10655759/968261).